# how to get mp4 download url

Tags: javascript, node.js, video

I wanna create a web site to download Twitch videos.

I saw the ***https://keepv.id/*** page source and confirmed that the href tag has a download link.

But I don't know how to make that link.

Is there any way or keyword that I can find?

Comment: Your question is currently too broad and isn't a good fit for SO. Please clarify your specific question.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I wanna make user downloads the mp4 video when user click button. In the case of Keepvid, when I search for a video, download button has a link `http://178.17.174.169/d/P2w9aHR0cHMl......`. I was wondering how to make url like this.

Comment: Use `download="video-bla-bla.mp4"` attribute in the `a` tag

Comment: Thanks for comment. I know using `download` property in `a` tag, but what I want is how to make the video download url link